# Looking for an online resource of the commentary(SNA.ii.476; SA.i.155) which says that the Brahma Sahampati was an Anagami from the Suddhavasa realms

Tags: reference-request, brahma, anagami, commentary

[This page](http://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/sahampati/index.html) mentions the following:

> The Commentaries say (SNA.ii.476; SA.i.155) that he was an Anagami
>   Brahma born in the Suddhavasa, there to pass a whole kappa...

I'm looking for an online resource for SNA.ii.476; SA.i.155.

Thanks!

Comment: In what language?

Comment: ven. @yuttadhammo, Pali is fine, Bhante! It would be fun to decipher. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sutta Nipata source is Sn-A 3.10:

Roman Pali:

http://tipitaka.org/romn/cscd/s0505a.att2.xml

Sinhalese Pali:

http://tipitaka.org/sinh/cscd/s0505a.att2.xml

The relevant passage is:

Atha kho brahmā sahampatīti ko ayaṃ brahmā, kasmā ca bhagavantaṃ upasaṅkamitvā etadavocāti? Ayaṃ kassapassa bhagavato sāsane sahako nāma bhikkhu **anāgāmī hutvā suddhāvāsesu uppanno, tattha naṃ ‘‘**sahampati brahmā’’ti sañjānanti.**

අථ ඛො බ්‍රහ්‌මා සහම්‌පතීති කො අයං බ්‍රහ්‌මා, කස්‌මා ච භගවන්‌තං උපසඞ්‌කමිත්‌වා එතදවොචාති? අයං කස්‌සපස්‌ස භගවතො සාසනෙ සහකො නාම භික්‌ඛු අනාගාමී හුත්‌වා සුද්‌ධාවාසෙසු උප්‌පන්‌නො, තත්‌ථ නං ‘‘සහම්‌පති බ්‍රහ්‌මා’’ති සඤ්‌ජානන්‌ති.

Roughly:

"And then the Brahma Sahampati" - Who was this brahma? And from what [cause] did he, having approached, say this? This one, a bhikkhu named Sahaka in the sasana of the Kassapa the Blessed One, having become an anagami, arose in the Pure Abodes; there, they knew him as "Sahampati Brahma".

Comment: Sādhu Bhante! I've also heard that he had already attained Arahantship by the time he invited the Buddha to preach the Dhamma.

Comment: I'm guessing it says "Sahampathi Brahma was ordained by the name of 'Sahako' and got the upasampada in the Sasana of Kassapa Buddha. He became an Anagami and was born in Suddhavasa. He was called by the name 'Sahampathi' by his fellow Brahmas."?  I probably butchered it! :D

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille well done :) I added a translation.